# How to override field in create method only if it is provided

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have overridden the save method to inherit from a field of a different model. However, I want to inherit only if I am not passing the value of that field while creating the object. If the value is passed while creating the object, I don't want it to inherit.

I have two models:

`Product` having fields `type` (foreign key) and `should_remove`

`Type` having fields `name` and `should_remove`

When I create a new Product entry without passing `should_remove` it automatically inherits from the `Type` which is correct.

```
type = Type.objects.create(name="open", should_remove=False)
product = Product.objects.create(type=type)
product.should_remove # False
```

However, if I pass the `should_remove` field it still inherits from the `Type`

```
type = Type.objects.create(name="open", should_remove=False)
product = Product.objects.create(type=type, should_remove=True)
product.should_remove # False
```

My idea is to access the value of passed `should_remove` inside the `save()` method and set it only if it is passed. How do I access the passed value in the save method?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # How do I access the passed should_remove here??
    if not self.id:
        self.should_remove = self.type.should_remove
    super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: which version of django are you using? and is `should_remove` defined as a `BooleanField`?

Comment: I am using Django 1.11.20 final and yes `should_remove` is a `BooleanField`

Comment: You could try using a `NullBoleanField` with default value `None` so if it’s still `None` (`is None`) when saving, you know it wasn’t set. If it’s set, then you don’t override it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # How do I access the passed should_remove here??
    should_remove = kwargs.get("should_remove")
    # . . .
```

Comment: Nope, the kwargs just has `'using': 'default', 'force_insert': True`

Comment: Just noticed that you are passing it into `create`, but overriding `save`